# How to Automatically reload views in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm looking to reload a view every time a user changes/updates their profile information in settings which are then stored in CoreData. So for example, I have three views that use CoreData information that has been stored. however, they don't automatically refresh on their own after a change. Pull to refresh is literally the last solution I'm looking for, but I would want something similar to the Apple App store as it seems that its views refresh on a given interval or user launch of the app. How could I achieve that? (they don't use pull to refresh)

This is what I have

class updateHome: ObservableObject {

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Account.userID, ascending: true)],predicate: NSPredicate(format: "userID == %@", Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid), animation: .default) private var savedAccounts: FetchedResults<Account>
@State private var currentAccount: Account?

@State var showAlert = false
@State var alertMessage = ""
@State var alertTitle = ""



func reloadview() {
    
    
    currentAccount = savedAccounts.first
    
    if currentAccount == nil {
    let userDataToSave = Account (context: viewContext)
        userDataToSave.firstname = Auth.auth().currentUser!.displayName
        userDataToSave.lastname = Auth.auth().currentUser!.displayName
        userDataToSave.userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
```

userDataToSave.profileImage = nil

```
        do {
            
            try viewContext.save()
            
        } catch let error {
            
            alertTitle = "Uh-Oh!"
             alertMessage = error.localizedDescription
             showAlert.toggle()
         }
    
}
    
}
```

}

I will get a crash if try to run this code on the homeview

```
            .onAppear() {
                
                currentAccount = savedAccounts.first!
        
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just use the `@ObservedObject` wrapper on the CoreData object when you want to see the CoreData changes

Comment: I tried this, but I got a crash or no changes were made. Not sure if its how its being used, but I can share the code.

Comment: `@Environment`, `@FetchRequest` and `@State` should only be used in a `struct` that is in a `View` you cannot put them in a `class` they will not work effectively. Also, CoreData objects are `ObservableObjects`. Wrapping a CoreData object means to do something like `@ObservedObject var currentAccount: Account` this will allow you to see changes. But you can only do this in a `struct` that is a `View` not a `class`.

Comment: Your should try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) it seems like you are pretty new to SwiftUI.

Comment: Yes i'm very new. I was following a course on Designcode.io and this is how they did it.

Comment: If they have those wrappers in a class vs a struct you should not rely on their tutorials.